# Is there any way to add components to jira issue using python jira client?

Tags: python, jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I was working on a project where I have to update jira issue fields like components , epic links,etc.
I am using jira python client(https://pypi.org/project/jira/) to do this task.

```
ticketObj = authJira.issue('ABC-12345')
print(ticketObj.fields.components)
```

This is outputing below results

```
[]
```

Because components is a array
So If want to update a field in the jissue I have to do the below things

```
ticketObj.update(components = ['component 1'])
```

But this method is giving below error

```
JiraError HTTP 400 url: https://jira.yourdomain.com/rest/api/2/issue/1234567
    text: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.atlassian.jira.rest.api.issue.FieldOperation] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.IssueUpdateBean["update"])
    
    response headers = {...}
    response text = {"errorMessages":["Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.atlassian.jira.rest.api.issue.FieldOperation] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.IssueUpdateBean[\"update\"])"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of this question, I researched everywhere and I sadly didn't find the method to add components using jira python client,so I created new method to add component which uses rest api provided by .

```
    def addComponentToTicket(self,ticketKey:str,component:str):
        payload = json.dumps({"update": {"components": [{
            "add": {"name": component}
        }], }})
        headers = { 
                           "Accept": "application/json",
                           "Content-Type": "application/json",
                           "Authorization":f'Bearer {self.personalAccessToken}',
                           "X-Atlassian-Token": "no-check",
                        }
        response = requests.put(f'{self.REST_URL}issue/{ticketKey}',
                                data=payload,
                                headers=headers,
                                verify=False)
```

I got another cleaner method, If We want to update any fields  of issue in jira we could use the Jira api method of updating by passing dictionary to update argument.

```
ticketObj.update(
    update=
        {
            "components": [{
                "add": {"name": component},
            }],
        },
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found following working (when updating component in existing issue)

```
 issue.update(notify=False,update={"components": [{"add": {"name": str(NAME),}}],},)
```

`NAME` being name of the component (must exist in the project)

Answer (score 1):

This works for the current version of Jira Cloud (Python 3)...

```
def addComponentToTicket(self, ticketKey: str, component: str):
    payload = json.dumps({"update": {"components": [{"add": {"name": component}}]}})
    url = self.server_url + f'/rest/api/latest/issue/{ticketKey}'
    response = requests.put(url,
                            auth=(f'{email}', f'{jira_token}'),
                            data=payload,
                            headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                            verify=False)
    if (response.status_code >= 200) and (response.status_code < 300):
        return response
    else:
        print(f'addComponentToTicket() Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}')

    return response


def setComponentsOfTicket(self, ticketKey: str, component_list: list):
    comp_set = []
    for c in component_list:
        comp_set.append({"name": c})
    payload = json.dumps({"update": {"components": [{"set": comp_set}]}})
    url = self.server_url + f'/rest/api/latest/issue/{ticketKey}'
    response = requests.put(url,
                            auth=(f'{email}', f'{jira_token}'),
                            data=payload,
                            headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                            verify=False)
    if (response.status_code >= 200) and (response.status_code < 300):
        return response
    else:
        print(f'setComponentsOfTicket() Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}')

    return response


def clearComponentsFromTicket(self, ticketKey: str):
    payload = json.dumps({"update": {"components": [{"set": []}]}})
    url = self.server_url + f'/rest/api/latest/issue/{ticketKey}'
    response = requests.put(url,
                            auth=(f'{email}', f'{jira_token}'),
                            data=payload,
                            headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                            verify=False)
    if (response.status_code >= 200) and (response.status_code < 300):
        return response
    else:
        print(f'clearComponentsFromTicket() Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}')

    return response

# Set the methods into the JIRA class... 
JIRA.addComponentToTicket = addComponentToTicket
JIRA.setComponentsOfTicket = setComponentsOfTicket
JIRA.clearComponentsFromTicket = clearComponentsFromTicket
```